# Starting with Qt - QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner in using Qt and I have a problem. I want to display red background using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. Instead of red, I'm still displaying the white one. I don't know, where the problem exists.

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QBrush>

class Screen:public QGraphicsView
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  Screen();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

Screen::Screen()
{

    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);

    scene->setBackgroundBrush(redBrush);
    view->setScene(scene);
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Screen scr;
    scr.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is there there are two different QGraphicsView objects being created -- one is the Screen object (scr), which is a subclass of QGraphicsView and therefore is a QGraphicsView object, and the other is the (view) object that you allocated with 'new' in the Screen constructor.

You're setting the scene attribute of the second one, but never showing it or doing anything with it.  You're seeing the first one displayed on screen (since that is the one you call show() on inside main()), but since you never set its scene attribute, it remains blank/white.

The easiest fix is to get rid of the unnecessary second QGraphicsView object.  I changed the Scene constructor to this:

```
Screen::Screen()
{
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::red);
    setScene(scene);
}
```

... and having done that, the program now displays the red window that you would expect.